C++: What does the (-1) mean at the end of the parameter list in this function?
I don't understand the definition of a function below: What does the (-1) mean at the end of the parameter list?
template<typename RatioT = std::milli>                
bool rclcpp::client::ClientBase::wait_for_service (std::chrono::duration< int64_t, RatioT > timeout = std::chrono::duration< int64_t, RatioT >(-1) )

Source:

https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1client_1_1ClientBase.html#a2999c323a3ee4935cd74d12675e668a0

From this tutorial:

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client.html


The default timeout is -1. Unrelated to your question: "You're reading the documentation for a version of ROS 2 that has reached its EOL (end-of-life), and is no longer officially supported. If you want up-to-date information, please have a look at Jazzy."

Thank your for your reply,
I think I got it.
default = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::mini>(-1).
I was just confused by this (-1). I still don't understand what a timeout of -1 could mean. But it's ok

Looks like wait_for_service is forwarding the call to wait_for_service_nanoseconds. You can have a look at the source to find out the exact behavior.

It is a default value. Set to an unlikely value that timeout should never have. I personally think this kind of API is bad (magic numbers). And there should have been a function overload that just doesn't accept a timeout at all, and the overload with timeout should never accept negative values. (e.g. what does an API like this do when you pass -2). So to me it is mostly bad API design

It means that the default value for the parameter is -1 (of whatever duration type, by default milliseconds). This value (or probably any negative value) is presumably used to denote "no timeout", however the documentation for this class is entirely silent on the meanings of any of the parameters to any of the member functions.

just for the nitpicks, the default value of the functions parameter is std::chrono::duration< int64_t, RatioT >(-1). The -1 is the parameter to the constructor to construct the default parameter.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I pronounce std::chrono::milliseconds(-1) as "-1 milliseconds"
